# Unknown command 'import-graphml', when trying to import into Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, graphml

It has been asked before, but in that case the problem was miraculously solved (https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools/issues/25). I, sadly, am not so lucky.

**Problem**: neo4j-shell does not recognize the import-graphml command.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ help import-graphml
No manual entry for 'import-graphml'
neo4j-sh (?)$ import-graphml -i /data/maorg.neo4j.shell.ShellException: Unknown command 'import-graphml'
```

**Question**: any suggestions on how to solve this, what have I missed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I assumed these tools were part of the neo4j-shell. However they require there own installation https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools